# There are $U$ and $W$ subspaces in the vectorspace of V.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What is the necessary but not sufficient condition, to exist a $\varphi$ linear mapping, for that $ Ker\ \varphi = U$ and $Im\ \varphi = W $

I still have no idea how to show that, should I maybe start to check the additivity and homogenity properties of a linear mapping?

Comment: "...to exist linear mapping..." ...from **where to where**? And are you sure you want *a subspace* $\;W\;$... **of a space** $\;W\;$ ??

Comment: Oh sorry I have edited the question --in the Vectorspace of V.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $\phi : V \to V$ is a linear mapping, then

$$\dim(\ker(\phi))+\dim(Im(\phi))=\dim(V)$$

**Hint 2** If  $\dim(U)+\dim(W)=\dim V$, pick a basis $B$ of $U$ and cmomplete it to a basis $B \cup B'$ of $V$.

Now there exists a bijection from $B'$ to a basis $B''$ of $W$.

Construct $\phi$ such that $\phi$ is zero on $B$ and $\phi$ is the above bijection on $B'$.